# Sassc installation problem - taking too long / crashing / timing out

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems

My ubuntu server (AWS lightsail) can't install sassc ruby gem, it just times out, other gems will install however. Is there an issue with sassc? is there a workaround?

The version is sass 2.4.0

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/issues/189. Does it work better with a lower version?

Comment: not sure how to override the default one it tries to grab? im not specifying it

Comment: What gem requires it? Look in Gemfile.lock. You could try `gem 'sassc', '~> 2.1.0'` in your Gemfile, but probaly won't work.